# Можно ли расширить раздел ext4?

Tags: linux

Можно ли расширить раздел `ext4`? С помощью какой программы/ каким способом лучше?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

*resize2fs* — программа для изменения места, занимаемого **файловой системой** *[ext2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2)/[ext3](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3)/[ext4](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)* **на разделе** (разделу блочного устройства, в общем-то, «всё равно», какая там файловая система создана внутри него, и создана ли вообще).

использование подробно описано в [`man resize2fs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/resize2fs.8.html).

общая информация: для уменьшения размера файловая система должна быть отмонтирована. для увеличения отмонтировать не обязательно, но в конце **раздела** должно быть свободное пространство. то есть сначала надо увеличить размер **раздела** (добавить свободное пространство в его конце), а уж затем вызывать *resize2fs* для увеличения размера **файловой системы**.

---

> каким способом лучше?

тому, кто задаётся подобным вопросом, вероятно, лучше воспользоваться «gui-обёрткой» вокруг *parted* под названием *gparted* (окно этой «обёртки» приведено на вашей картинке).

Comment: Из опыта могу ещё добавить, что лучше грузануться с отдельного livecd с gparted. Например http://gparted.org/livecd.php . Swap лучше убить и пересоздать (не забыв потом поправить fstab). И порядок будет примерно следующий: грузимся с livecd, убиваем свап, уменьшаем sda3, расширяем ext4, создаём новый swap и собсно на оставшееся место раздвигаем sda6. P.S.  очень старых версиях gparted ntfs раздел иногда убивался. Баг очень редко и очень давно вылазил, но бэкап при возможности лучше всё равно сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Самое главное в этом деле понимать, что партиция - это раздел, а файловая система - это нечто, помещённое в этот раздел, не обязательно по плащади равное этому разделу.

Аналогия: поле, разделённое межой. В каждом из разделов может быть засеяна зерном какая-то часть раздела, не обязательно равная этому разделу.

Так вот: при уменьшении размера раздела нужно сначала уменьшать размер файловой системы, затем уменьшать размер раздела.

При увеличении - наоборот, сначала увеличиваем раздел, затем - размер ФС.

Размер ФС изменяется resize2fs в случае если это ext2/3/4 ФС, в иных случаях есть иные утилиты, для xfs - xfs_growfs и т.п.

В твоём случае я, честно говоря, не вижу откуда ты можешь взять место для расширения - несчастный гиг в свопе ничем особо не поможет. Как вариант - урезать NTFS.

Вот пошаговая инструкция как это сделать из венды:
http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/shrink-and-extend-ntfs-volumes-in-windows/#shrink

В результате появится "сырое" (RAW) место, которое ты и используешь при помощи твоего gparted :)

Answer (score 0):

У меня centos7, но не суть, - из консоли (CLI) я сделал уменьшение одного раздела и увеличение другого так:

```
// уменьшение любого раздела
lvreduce -r -L -50G /dev/mapper/vg_dev-portal-lv_home
// просмотр свободно (неразмеченного) места :)
vgs
// увеличение любого раздела
lvextend -r -L +50G /dev/mapper/vg_dev-portal-lv_root
```

P.S: все разделы e меня ext4, но думаю даже если были бы разными - всё прошло хорошо)